Porque eslint me marca errores en todas las lineas?
bueno en definitiva es eso, eslint me esta marcando errores en todas las lineas de mi codigo, obviamente es un problema visual nada mas pero es molesto.
Este es el codigo en el config de eslint
module.exports = {
  extends: ["expo", "prettier"],
  plugins: ["prettier"],
  rules: {
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
  },
  ignorePatterns: ["*/dist/*"],
};



Y qué errores ves? Veo que está subrayado en rojo pero quisiera saber qué información te da

Gracias por la edicion! Ningun error perse, solo esos subrayados en rojo al final de cada linea
